# How to change the IP address in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy

req_proxy = RequestProxy()
proxies = req_proxy.get_proxy_list()    

brasa = [proxy for proxy in proxies if proxy.country == 'Brazil']

random = np.random.randint(0, 30)
PROXY = brasa[random].get_address()
    
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    }

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://whatsmyip.com/')
```

But, my IP doesn't change. I have tried others' answers, but they do not work.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to fix it:

```py
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxies)
```

Comment: Add this line before calling the webdriver.chrome() function. With this will pickup the proxy ip instead of your router ip. I had the similar issue and worked for me.